# PSQL User Cannot See Extensions Created By Superuser

Tags: postgresql, roles, psql

So I have created two extensions with my superuser but when I try to use these extensions as a (non-super) user, it cannot find them.

As superuser:

```
postgres=# SELECT e.extname
postgres-#      , n.nspname      AS home_schema_of_extension
postgres-#      , extrelocatable AS extension_can_be_relocated
postgres-# FROM   pg_catalog.pg_extension e
postgres-# JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = e.extnamespace;
    extname    | home_schema_of_extension | extension_can_be_relocated
---------------+--------------------------+----------------------------
 adminpack     | pg_catalog               | f
 plpgsql       | pg_catalog               | f
 fuzzystrmatch | public                   | t
 btree_gist    | public                   | t
(4 rows)
```

And as another user:

```
toggleme=> SELECT e.extname
toggleme->      , n.nspname      AS home_schema_of_extension
toggleme->      , extrelocatable AS extension_can_be_relocated
toggleme-> FROM   pg_catalog.pg_extension e
toggleme-> JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = e.extnamespace;
 extname | home_schema_of_extension | extension_can_be_relocated
---------+--------------------------+----------------------------
 plpgsql | pg_catalog               | f
(1 row)
```

Why is the non-super-user unable to use these extensions? Non-super-user has `public` in his search path but still can't even see that these extensions exist.

Comment: Note that you can also use `\dx` to list the extensions in `psql`. No need to remember that SQL query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The superuser and normal user are connected to different databases in the same PostgreSQL instance.

`CREATE EXTENSION` is database-local.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks, Craig.